# Use the "Media Library" in Frontend

Tags: media-library

Is it possible to show the media-library on a frontend template?

I need to use the media-library `(/wp-admin/upload.php)` as part of a frontend page design with some modifications. I dont want to use the upload-functionality but the list of all images and the functionality you have when clicking on one image... 
So, I need the css, php and js code of the wordpress media-library.

I could code this from scracth but I like the idea to re-use the wordpress-core code.
Where can I find the code in the wp-admin folder and how can i integrate this code on frontend?
Thanks alot

**Edit:**

i dont want to use media uploader i want to display the content of the media library on a page with (more or less) same design and fuctionality as in the backend.

like on this sketch:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add below code to your current theme's function.php

```
function add_media_upload_scripts() {
    if ( is_admin() ) {
         return;
       }
    wp_enqueue_media();
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_media_upload_scripts');
```

Further, you can explore more in detail by follow this blog (i.e. https://codestag.com/how-to-use-wordpress-3-5-media-uploader-in-theme-options/)

Comment: thanks, i edited my question to make it more clear what i need to achieve.

Comment: I'm not fond of the implementation but the answer to my problem with the Media Library not loading in the frontend was to use wp_enqueue_media()